# Is there a way to hide the backup files in the "Current Folder" pane in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB automatically generates backup files. For example, if I have a file called "simulation.m", after some editing MATLAB automatically generates a file called "simulation.m~" in the same folder. While it is a nice feature, I don't want to see them in the "Current Folder" pane. Is there a way to hide them? Thanks!

Not sure if relevant, I am using R2010b in a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File -> Preferences... -> Current Directory -> Show filter Field. Then you can enter `*.m` in the new field that showed up on the top of the "Currecnt Directory" pane.

See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bropbi9-1.html#bropbja-27

> The Current Directory browser includes new ways to navigate and to view the directory contents. There are also new ways to find files, including a new filter field.
>
> - List only files whose names contain a specified string by using the new filter field. To show the filter field, use File > Preferences > Current Directory.

See also: http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/matlab/144886/Where-has-Current-Directory-gone

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have a "Current Directory" pane inside Preferences... There is one for "Current Folder" but it doesn't have a "Show Filter Field". What version/OS do you have?

Comment: See links. The feature was added on R2008b.

Comment: I guess there's no way to hide the .m~ files then. "Group by"->"Type" is close enough... thanks!